# Description of STM32f4xx standard peripheral library

Tags: c, embedded, arm, stm32

Is there a good description of the STM432f4xx libraries along the lines of the really good one available for the [stm32f2xx library](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00023896.pdf), or is the 32f4xx entirely self documented through comments and examples?

It's great to have this available all in one doc, as opposed to wading through the library tree. It looks like much of what applies to the framework is already in the f2xx description, but I just wanted to be sure, despite my fruitless searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, here are the most helpful sources (imo) other than the ref manual, and source. 'Tis all about formatting:

[CMSIS Library](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/DSP/html/modules.html)

[Github STM32F4 Standard Peripheral Lib Documentation](https://github.com/mfauzi/STM32F4/tree/master/STM32F4%20Standard%20Peripheral%20Library/Libraries/CMSIS/Documentation)

[Reference Manuals](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/search.html#q=support-t=products-page=1)

[Programming Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/6c/3a/cb/e7/e4/ea/44/9b/DM00046982.pdf/files/DM00046982.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00046982.pdf)

*Note the use of DOXYGEN to generate some sources*

Comment: Thanks, nice resources.  It actually does come down to formatting, and an interface that facilitates exploration

Answer (score 2):

The source comments are in [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) markup. Doxygen is an open source documentation generator and source code analyser, you can use it to generate the documentation yourself in various formats such as HTML, LaTex and PDF.  The library itself includes this documentation as a CHM (compiled HTML help file).

Answer (score 1):

The best descriptions of the library functions are found in the source files themselves.  Other than that, you can turn to the reference manual.  It'll give you a lower, register-level understanding of how to configure your microcontroller.